# select2 with size attribute for single selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm using an amazing plugin [select2](https://select2.github.io/) for select boxes with input search like this:

[image]

I want to keep it **open** like this:

[image]

They have a lot of documentation and you can find a lot about it here, but I can't find something about the **size attribute** for single selection, not multiple. It must be searchable and scrollable for long list.

I'd tried using multiple selection limiting the number of selection to one, but it behave wrong because the list disappear after selection. Maybe, that's a good approach, but I'm stuck. And also, I can't implement the size attribute to multiple selection with this plugin.

The only thing I could find was the option for keep it open after selection, `closeOnSelect: false` [like](https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-i-prevent-the-dropdown-from-closing-when-a-result-is-select) this:

```js
$('#selectTypeTransaction').select2({
  placeholder: "Select Transaction Type",
  width: '250px',
  theme: "classic",
  closeOnSelect: false
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select size="5">
<option></option>
  <option value="one">Income</option>
  <option value="two">Outcome</option>
  <option value="three">Transfer</option>
</select>
 VS 
<select id="selectTypeTransaction" class="form-control select2-single">
<option></option>
  <option value="one">Income</option>
  <option value="two">Outcome</option>
  <option value="three">Transfer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a proper way to do it ?

Comment: sadly no, I have to put that project on hold